# Build the calendar table for current year including weeknum divided to semester

Tags: t-sql

for the below query i need divide the semesters starting from 1 to 26 .. first semester as 1 to 26 weeks and first semester should start from again 1 to 26

### Any help is greating appreciated

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME 
DECLARE @CutoffDate DATETIME 

SET @StartDate = Dateadd(yy, Datediff(yy, 0, Getdate()), 0) 
SET @CutoffDate = Dateadd(yy, Datediff(yy, 0, Getdate()) + 1, -1) 

SELECT day, 
       [week nu], 
       semester, 
       [semester week nu] 
INTO   #currentdates 
FROM   (SELECT Day = Dateadd(day, rn - 1, @StartDate), 
               Datepart(week, Dateadd(day, rn - 1, @StartDate)) [Week nu], 
               CASE 
                 WHEN Month(Dateadd(day, rn - 1, @StartDate)) <= 6 THEN 
                 'First Semester' 
                 ELSE 'Second Semester' 
               END                                              AS Semester, 
               Datepart(week, Dateadd(day, rn - 1, @StartDate)) AS 
               [Semester Week nu] 
        FROM   (SELECT TOP (Datediff(day, @StartDate, @CutoffDate)) rn = 
               Row_number() 
                       OVER ( 
                         ORDER BY s1.[object_id]) 
                FROM   sys.all_objects AS s1 
                       CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2 
                ORDER  BY s1.[object_id]) AS x) AS y;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a couple of changes, first, you need to add 1 to your last datediff, your last date was December 30, not 31!

Second of all, I just get the date and week number in the first subselect, and then use these ine case statements for the select

The semester number is if week nu<=26, 
The semester week nu is week nu if week nu<=26 else wwek nu -26

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime DECLARE @CutoffDate datetime
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
SET @CutoffDate = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1)
SELECT DAY,
       [Week nu],
       case when [Week nu]<=26 then 'First Semester' Else 'Second Semester' end Semester,
       case when [Week nu]<=26 then [Week nu] Else [Week nu]-26 end[Semester Week nu] 
       INTO #currentDates
FROM
  (SELECT DAY = DATEADD(DAY, rn - 1, @StartDate),
                DATEPART(WEEK,DATEADD(DAY, rn - 1, @StartDate)) [Week nu]

   FROM
     (SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @CutoffDate)+1) rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
      FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
      CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
      ORDER BY s1.[object_id]) AS x) AS y;
```

Comment: Much appreciate your response.. Thanks!